# check if csv file is empty and throw error if empty

Tags: scala, file, dataframe, apache-spark

I have directory which is containing multiple csv file as below:

```
x1.csv
x2.csv
x3.csv
x4.csv
```

i am reading all the csv file in a dataframe using :

```
def getCSVData(path: String): Either[Throwable, DataFrame] = {
    try{
       Right(sc.read.format("csv")
      .option("delimiter",",")
      .schema(MSchema)
      .option("header","true")
      .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
      .load(path)
       )
    }catch {
      case e: ControlThrowable => throw e
      case e: Throwable => {
        log.error("getCSVData failed", e)
        Left(e)
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I am not sure to include empty file check in this and raise an error if the particular file is empty.

For e.g., if x3 file is empty and x1,x2, and x4 have data then it should raise an error that x3 file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileSystem to list the files in a directory and filter out the files with No records.

```
val dataPath = "<your directory location>"

val filesystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())

val fileStatus = filesystem.listStatus(new Path(dataPath))

fileStatus.foreach{
   x => x.getLen match {
     case 0 => println("Found Empty File :"+x.getPath.getName)
     case _ => println("Found NON Empty File :"+x.getPath.getName)
  }
}
```

You can include your logic to handle inside the foreach section.

Hope this helps :)